# Querying posts globally based on custom taxonomy with its own taxonomymeta table

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, pre-get-posts, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have gone through the process of creating a custom taxonomy + admin panel for a custom post type in my site. These taxonomies store various meta data in a `wp_taxonomymeta` table and use get_metadata/set_metadata to get and set the values of these fields. One of the fields in this taxonomy is an enabled/disabled flag.

I would like to globally exclude posts that have the disabled flag set to true. I am hooking into `pre_get_posts`, but I cannot figure out how to modify the query so that I can pull data in the `wp_taxonomymeta` for use in the query to exclude posts that should be hidden. Can anyone provide some insight into doing this? I could not find much helpful advice on google. If clarification is needed, please ask, I will do my best to clear anything confusing up.

**EDIT FROM COMMENTS**

I'm trying to modify the main query. The idea is ultimately to be able to hide/show globally across the site based on the taxonomy's meta data flag value. So I have a plugin that implements a `pre_get_posts` hook, but I cannot get the query figured out with the custom table (at least in the typical wordpress fashion, raw SQL would be cake, but I'm wanting to modify the main query).

There's not a lot of documentation around for working with these taxonomy tables since it seems to be a disputed way of doing stuff in wordpress.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the main query, or just creating a new custom query. Have a look at `WP_Query`'s custom parameters so long.

Comment: Trying to modify the main query. The idea is ultimately to be able to hide/show globally across the site based on the taxonomy's meta data flag value. So I have a plugin that implements a pre_get_posts hook, but I cannot get the query figured out with the custom table (at least in the typical wordpress fashion, raw SQL would be cake, but I'm wanting ot modify the main query). There's not a lot of documentation around for working with these taxonomy tables since it seems to be a disputed way of doing stuff in wordpress. :/

Answer (score 0):

For those running into issues in the future, this is what I did:

I made my `pre_get_posts` function that queries the taxonomy as normal for testing if an taxonomy ID is not in a list:

```
            $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tax',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => tax_get_inactive(),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )));
```

Then, I implemented my `tax_get_inactive` function as seen above, to query my `taxonomymeta` table and build an exclusion list. Not the most elegant way, but it works and the exclusion list can easily be cached if performance is in mind.